# Obtain location coordinates from UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to obtain the coordinates of a UIButton that is in a subview of the mainviewcontroller.  I can return them relative to the subview with the code below but how do I return the UIButton location as it relates to the mainviewcontroller?

ScrollingAppDelegate *appDelegate = (ScrollingAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
CGPoint canXY = appDelegate.globalcanButtonReference.frame.origin;
NSLog(@"%f %f",canXY.x,canXY.y);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a reference to all of the views, this should work:

```
CGPoint buttonOrigin = appDelegate.globalcanButtonReference.frame.origin;
CGPoint superViewOrigin = appDelegate.globalcanButtonReference.superview.frame.origin;
CGPoint pointInMainViewController = CGPointMake(buttonOrigin.x + superViewOrigin.x, buttonOrigin.y + superViewOrigin.y);
```